# BackToMyMac is periodically not working

Tags: macos, ssh

I am using BackToMyMac to ssh from my home mac to my work mac. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't work, it can't connect at all. Multiple times I've been able to connect, do some work, disconnected, then tried connecting again an hour later and was unable to. I am certain this is not because the computer is in sleep mode.

How do I go about diagnosing this issue?

Here is my ssh output:

```
~/>ssh -6 -vvv USER@COMPUTERNAME.ACCOUNTNUMBER.members.btmm.icloud.com

OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011

debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/USER/.ssh/config

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *

debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to COMPUTERNAME.ACCOUNTNUMBER.members.btmm.icloud.com [fd3a:717d:c227:d36b:705f:ef3c:8921:7c56] port 22.

debug1: connect to address fd3a:717d:c227:d36b:705f:ef3c:8921:7c56 port 22: Operation timed out

ssh: connect to host COMPUTERNAME.ACCOUNTNUMBER.members.btmm.icloud.com port 22: Operation timed out
```